# Failed to convert from type [java.util.ArrayList<?>] error when using join query in IgniteRepository

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, ignite

I am getting an exception while using the join query in IgniteRepository.

```
@Query(" select pers.* from Person as pers, ORG_CACHE.Organization as org where pers.orgId = org.id and lower(org.name) = lower(?)")
List<Person> selectPersonByOrganization(String organizationName);
```

Exception:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2020-07-09T05:02:16.141+0000",
  "message": "Failed to convert from type [java.util.ArrayList<?>] to type [@org.apache.ignite.springdata22.repository.config.Query java.util.List<com.cache.entity.Person>] for value '[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8]'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Long] to type [@org.apache.ignite.springdata22.repository.config.Query com.cache.entity.Person]",
  "details": "uri=/person/organization/ApacheIgnite"
}
```

Also wanted to know will the join be distributed or Colocated.

**Apache Ignite: 2.8.1
Sparing Data : ignite-spring-data_2.2**

Comment: if org.id is primary key and pers.orgId is affinity key, then it can be collocated.

Comment: org.id is primary key for ORG_CACHE . But i want the join to be distributed. How do i specify that. Also the JPA query is not working

Comment: I don't think you can enforce distributed join sin 2.8.1's Spring Data. It's expected in 2.9

Comment: thanks, @alamar  any idea how to use Entity directly in join instead of an individual field in join query response?